# Updating an int column with specific number

Tags: sql

I want to update a column of my table by some offset. Right now i am using this

```
SELECT FROM reward where id = xx
$score = id->score + 1;
then
UPDATE reward SET score = $score WHERE id = xx
```

is there a way instead of using two queries i can just do `UPDATE SET score = score + 1` ?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what you can do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you NEED to select it from another table you could do:

```
update reward set score = (select score from reward where id = xx) + 1 where id = xx
```

Or if you just need to increment that score by one:

```
UPDATE reward SET score = score + 1 WHERE id = xx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're lookling to increment by one try:

```
UPDATE reward SET score = score + 1 WHERE id = xx
```

If you want to add the reward:

```
UPDATE reward SET score = score + reward WHERE id = xx
```